# jQuery Ajax Post to php file on an other server is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, server

I'am programming a tool, in which you can link my JavaScript file to your website, and this JavaScript file does a ajax post to a PHP file on MY server.

The crazy Thing is that when I link the JavaScript file to a page on my webserver, it works, but when I link the JavaScript file on another website (which has another server) It doesn't works... Here the code:

phpwrite2.php: (The file which should create a file on my server)

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']);
    exit();
}

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


$myFile = $_POST['filename'];
$myFile = "users/".$myFile;

chmod("users/",0777);

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_POST["name"];
fwrite($fh, $stringData."\n");
fclose($fh);
?>
```

And the jQuery which does the ajax post to the phpwrite2.php file:

```
function writeToFile() {
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://alexehgm.myhostpoint.ch/phpwrite2.php',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: '{"name":name, "filename" : filename}',
        dataType: 'txt',
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var value = responseData.someKey;
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('POST failed.');
        }
    });
```

Thanks for reading my question, I hope you pros know a solution or find the fault.

Comment: You need to send [CORS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) headers on your server side to not get restricted.

Comment: @AndreasScheibleger Hello, THanks for your reply. Could you explain, what this CORS is and how tp use it? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically it comes down to sending the correct CORS headers on OPTIONS request (the preflight request) in addition with a header on the successive requests:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']);
    exit();
}

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
// Your code here
```

Explanation:

- `Acess-Control-Allow-Origin`: Sets the Domains that are allowed to
  access this resource.
- `Acess-Control-Allow-Methods`: Sets the HTTP methods that are allowed to access the resource.
- `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`: These are the additional headers that are allowed. You can use the requested headers to simply allow all requested. This cannot be `*`.

Comment: Thank yo for your answer! But unfortunately it still doesnt works :(. This is my code now in php: view edited question

Comment: What do you see in your network console in your browser? Are there any hints on restricted access?

Comment: No evereything seems to be okay

Comment: Do you see the preflight request? If yes, do you get the correct response headers? What is the status code and response of your actual request according to your network console?

Comment: @andread scheibleger actually, i see nothing in the console. Could you send me a complete, theoretically working code from the javascript and the php file? :D

Comment: If you do not see anything, then the request is not even performed, you have to check your page where the request should be sent. Just to be sure: Don't look at the javascript console, but the network tab of your developer tools in your browser.

Comment: So i added an alert when the post method fails, know i know that the post method is failing. When i klick on phpwrite2.php on the network console, it shows this: Warning: fopen(users/) [function.fopen.php]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in /home/alexehgm/www/alexehgm.myhostpoint.ch/phpwrite2.php on line 18
can't open file

Comment: Then the request on Client side succeeded, You just have an error in your server side script. Check your Post data and paths. Especially the filename.

Comment: But the Thing is that it works when i link the script to a page on my server

Comment: Nevertheless you get an error from server side. Therefore you have to check whether you are passing the correct data to your Server side script. I assume that you don't get correct POST data because it is trying to access `/user` without any filename. That's why i asked you to check your post data. You can see sent data in the network tab of developer tools and you could do `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you get on server side.

Comment: So, i deleted the user folder and tried to write the file in the same directory as the phpwrite2.php file... Still doesnt work.. Any other Ideas? btw. Thanks for your work

Comment: Did you look at your post data? What data is sent and what is the output of your var_dump?

Comment: What exactly is it showing and what's the error message you get?